# Javascript date validation?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, reactjs

I have this validation in my code:

```
  }
        if(!$('#date').val() ) {
            toastr.warning('Incomplete date field');
            return; 
       }
```

How can i do a validation that my input #date could not be bigger than current date? or getdate() ?

i was traying

```
 }
            if(!$('#date').val() )> date.now {
                toastr.warning('Check date');
                return; 
           }
```

But it doesn´t work

Comment: First of all, `> date.now` should be in the parenthses. Second, the value of #date is as a string, you have to convert it to a date object in order to compare it to another date.

Comment: Hey Lopez, the first thing you would normally want to do is confirm the date format you are getting from the form. Assuming for a moment you are getting a valid Unix epoch time value try `(Math.abs($('#date').val()) < Date.now() ) `

Answer (score 0):

`Date.now()` returns current timestamp (the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC). It can be compared to another timestamp like this:

```
if (timestamp > Date.now()) {
    toastr.warning('Check date');
    return; 
}
```

`timestamp` here needs to be obtained from the input value by converting the text to [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Date object supports several formats, see examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).

Assuming `#data` input has value of `2021-12-31`, `timestamp` will be 1640908800000 and `Check date` warning will be shown:

```
// $('#date').val() is '2020-11-20'
const dateObject = new Date($('#date').val());
const timestamp = dateObject.getTime();
// timestamp is 1640908800000
// Date.now() is 1605139119142
// 1640908800000 > 1605139119142
if (timestamp > Date.now()) {
    toastr.warning('Check date');
    return; 
}
```

*P.S.* Please mind that JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `Date` is not the same as `date`.

*P.P.S.* Parsing dates (especially time) with Date object has many issues, so many libraries were created to do it in a reliable way. For example, [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com) and [date-fns](https://date-fns.org).